# Redirect to correct page of the List after Delete

Tags: reactjs, react-router, material-ui, admin-on-rest

I have a List with default pagination. Each entry in the List can be deleted using the Delete button. The Delete button is the admin-on-rest Delete. Clicking Delete button takes me to a new page where the user is asked to confirm the action. On confirm, the user is redirected back to the page the item was on, so if the item was on page 2 of the list, they are redirected back to page 2 after the confirmation. This is the default behaviour of the admin-on-rest Delete.

The problem is, if page 2 has only one item and it is deleted, it redirects me to page 2 with an empty table and no arrows to navigate to first page. I have to do a browser refresh to fix it.

I noticed that in admin-on-rest version 1.3.3 there is a prop called "redirect" that the Delete accepts. I can set the redirect path of the previous page if the the row to be deleted is the only row on the page. But I cant figure out how to get the number of rows on the page. The admin-on-rest List component does not expose the pagination component which keeps information about the current page like page number, rows in the page etc.

Has anyone else had this issue? How do I get around it?

Comment: after going through documentation probably the best way is to file an issue about thins in their github. Described by you logic fits into common sense.

Comment: @zmii Okay. Any suggestion for time being?

Comment: write custom persistence handler that will store in localStorage metadata information about paginated list (number of items in the list, number of items on the page, sequential number of item clicked on current page, current page) - then after clicking final DELETE button look if any information was persisted and redirect accordingly.

Comment: @zmii information about the paginated list is not exposed anywhere.

Comment: Please open an issue about it in our repository

Comment: @Gildas I did, its not been responded to. Here https://github.com/marmelab/admin-on-rest/issues/1370

Comment: I'll see what we can do